# How do I list the content of a directory in the terminal without a command?

Tags: console

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbDYLUuwnTk&index=15&list=PLhQjrBD2T383Q2VtqEaQn8nZh-681av20) in the minute 16:10 he shows the content of a directory without a command. How do I do that?

Comment: That's [tab completion](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He types `cp /path/` and then repeatedly presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get the contents of the directory displayed.